# Creating dynamic virtual directories like Facebook usernames

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a functionality to my website that allows users to pick a username and then be able to access their page using www.thisismysite.com/theirusername I have searched all over google but im not really even sure what im looking for.

I want the same functionality as facebook usernames for example http://www.facebook.com/jason.vearncombe

Anyone have any ideas?

BTW im using asp.net c#

Comment: What version of asp.net are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily with Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#optionals-and-defaults

In MVC, a url does not need to map to a file or a directory. A url can be mapped to a function, the parts of the url will then be the parameter of the function. Such functions are called Action methods. Mapping a url to an action is called Routing. MVC framework allows you to define routes, then the framework will parse the url and does its magic to call your Action methods.